# How to enable of disable vSphere HA using Python SDK API

Tags: vsphere, esxi, vcenter

In vSphere UI there is a button to turn on or off vSphere HA, Cluster > Configure > vSphere Availability > vSphere HA is Turned ON > Edit > vSphere HA.

What is the correct [API reference object](https://vmware.github.io/vsphere-automation-sdk-python/vsphere/8.0.0.1/index.html) that will achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
def disableVcenterHighAvailabilityMode(vsan_client, clusterName):
    print("Disabling vSphere HA Mode.")
    cluster = getClusterInstance(clusterName, vsan_client)
    clusterConfigSpec = vim.cluster.ConfigSpec()
    clusterConfigSpec.dasConfig = cluster.configuration.dasConfig
    clusterConfigSpec.dasConfig.enabled = False
    cluster.ReconfigureCluster_Task(clusterConfigSpec, True)
```